# mod_rewrite: Help to rewrite an URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website and I'm trying to rewrite it's url.

It's pretty simple, but i'm not understanding how to do it.

The pages are the next ones:

**http://localhost/site/index.php?p=home**, etc. home is a parameter, and rewrite should be like this: **http://localhost/site/home.html**

**http://localhost/site/section.php?id=someid** and i want it to be like **http://localhost/site/the-name-of-the-section-from-database-SOMEID**

**http://localhost/site/product.php?id=someid** and i want it to be like **http://localhost/site/category-name/product-name-SOMEID**

I think it's simple, but I still don't understand how to do it. Please, help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I may be wrong, but you can't use modrewrite locally. Well I can't anyways, if I'm proven wrong I would love to know how!

Comment: it's possible to use it locally, I had a site with mod_rewrite enabled, and it worked.

Comment: ok, so whats the problem then? You have't provided any of your rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these lines in your ROOT .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^site/(home)\.html/?$ site/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Assuming hyphen is not in the section name
RewriteRule ^site/.*-(.*)/?$ site/section.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Assuming hyphen is not in the product name
RewriteRule ^site/[^/]*/.*-(.*)/?$ site/product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

this page shoul help you [.htaccess Url Rewrite Generator](http://www.myseotool.com/free-seo-tools/htaccess-url-rewrite-generator.php). it generates htaccess files for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/
use this link in has a detail ehplanation about mod_rewrite.also i think anubhava got the regex right